# Как правильно передать сообщить компилятору о типе в TS

Tags: typescript, типы

Есть вот такой код:

```
import Events from 'backbone-events-standalone';

class A {

 constructor(){
  Object.assign(this, Events);
 }

 doSomething(){
  this.trigger();
 }

}
```

Отнаследоваться не могу, потому что импортируется инстанс объекта.

Описания типов для этой библиотеки нет, но есть для Backbone.

```
declare module 'backbone-events-standalone' {

    import Backbone = require('backbone');

    export default Backbone.Events;

}
```

Однако компилятор TS ругается :

> Error:(143, 9) TS2339: Property 'trigger' does not exist on type 'EventBus'.

Предлагали вот такие варианты [решениния](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901683/how-to-tell-typescript-compile-about-not-explicit-inheritance) , но ошибка осталась, хотя webstorm уже пути находил.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что пишут в документации про [миксины](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html):

> To satisfy this requirement, we create stand-in properties and their types for the members that will come from our mixins. This satisfies the compiler that these members will be available at runtime. This lets us still get the benefit of the mixins, albeit with some bookkeeping overhead.

То есть, интерфейс миксина всё-таки придётся продублировать.

```
type IEvents = typeof Events;

class A implements IEvents {
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, Events);
    }

    trigger: (name: string) => this;
}
```